# Can not remove my Gutenberg block. It has been fixed on editor page

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I just tried to render some post data through PHP. After that the block is stack on editor page. Is there any problem in my code?

Note: Before query posts in PHP file I can't see this problem. Maybe I've a mistake in PHP file. But I don't know.

On php file

```
/*
Plugin Name: Gutenberg examples 01
*/

/**
 * Renders the post block on server.
 */
function post_layouts_block_render_block_core( $attributes ) {

    $args       = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
    );
    $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {

        $list_items_markup = '<div id="forhad-guten-posts"><ul>';
        while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {

            $post_query->the_post();
            $list_items_markup .= '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
        $list_items_markup .= '</ul></div>';
        return $list_items_markup;
    }
}

// Register Block and initial setupment
function gutenberg_examples_01_register_block() {

    // automatically load dependencies and version.
    $asset_file = include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.asset.php';

    wp_register_script(
        'gutenberg-examples-01-esnext',
        plugins_url( 'build/index.js', __FILE__ ),
        $asset_file['dependencies'],
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.js' ),
        true,
    );

    wp_register_style(
        'gutenberg-examples-01-editor',
        plugins_url( 'src/editor.css', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-edit-blocks' ),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'src/editor.css' ), // filemtime() returns the last time of when its content was modified.
    );

    wp_register_style(
        'gutenberg-examples-01',
        plugins_url( 'src/style.css', __FILE__ ),
        array(),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'src/style.css' ), // filemtime() returns the last time of when its content was modified.
    );

    register_block_type(
        'gutenberg-examples/example-01-basic-esnext',
        array(
            'api_version'     => 2,
            'style'           => 'gutenberg-examples-01',
            'editor_style'    => 'gutenberg-examples-01-editor',
            'editor_script'   => 'gutenberg-examples-01-esnext',
            'render_callback' => 'post_layouts_block_render_block_core',
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'gutenberg_examples_01_register_block' );
```

On JS file

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { RichText, InspectorControls, ColorPalette, MediaUpload } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { PanelBody, Button, RangeControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import ServerSideRender from '@wordpress/server-side-render';

registerBlockType( 'gutenberg-examples/example-01-basic-esnext', {
    title: 'Basic Example',
    icon: 'smiley',
    category: 'design',

    /**
     * Custom attributes :
     * -------------------
     */
     attributes: {

        titleColor: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'black',
        },
        overlayOpacity: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 0.3
        },
    },

    edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {

        const {
            titleColor,
            overlayOpacity
        } = attributes;

        function onTitleColorChange( newColor ) {

            setAttributes({ titleColor: newColor });
        }
        function onOverlayOpacityChange( newOpacity ) {

            setAttributes({ overlayOpacity: newOpacity });
        }

        return ([
            <InspectorControls style={{ marginBottom: '40px' }}>
                {/* https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/panel/#design-guidelines */}
                <PanelBody title={ 'Font Color Settings' }>
                    <p><strong>Select a Title color:</strong></p>
                    <ColorPalette value={ titleColor }
                                  onChange={ onTitleColorChange } />
                </PanelBody>

                <PanelBody title={ 'Background Image Settings' }>
                    <RangeControl
                        label={ 'Overlay Opacity' }
                        value={ overlayOpacity }
                        onChange={ onOverlayOpacityChange }
                        min={ 0 }
                        max={ 1 }
                        step={ 0.01 } />
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>,

            // Posts direct show from 'render_callback' on the editor.
            <div><p>Posts are showing here: yaaaaaa</p>
            <ServerSideRender
                block={ "gutenberg-examples/example-01-basic-esnext" } />
            </div>
        ]);
    },

    // Render via PHP
    save() {
        return null;
    },

} );
```

After all I've another question about 'ServerSideRender'. Is it possible to get values from `block={ "gutenberg-examples/example-01-basic-esnext" }`? Otherwise I don't apply the $variables in JS file.

Comment: Your Block & Data is basically just written into the Post. So if you look at the code view on the page, you'll see all of the attributes etc. in there. So worst case if it gets "stuck", just delete the markup through your editor.

Comment: I don't even remove the block after adding block once

Answer (score 2):

Finally, it's done by adding `...useBlockProps()`

```
<div { ...useBlockProps() }>
  <ServerSideRender
    block={ "gutenberg-examples/example-01-basic-esnext" } />
</div>
```

Just make sure to import `useBlockProps` before using it.

```
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
```

Now block core options are shown after selecting the block.